# Regular expression matching LINE but NOT a single special word

Tags: regex

I have a regex matching a *line* having the word "Mq\w+GetContext"…

```
^.*Mq\w+GetContext.*$
```

example: *MqBufferGetContext*, *MqDumpGetContext*, *MqErrorGetContext* etc

and NOW my problem… I **dont't** want to have the *line* matching the word…

```
MqErrorGetContext
```

try to use

```
^.*Mq(?!Error)GetContext.*$
```

does not work.

Comment: NO! - I want to have all lines matching "^.*Mq\w+GetContext.*$" but NOT the line containing "MqErrorGetContext"

Comment: So you want things like `MqBufferGetContext, MqDumpGetContext` to be one whole match?

Comment: NO! - I want to match single line containing **ONE OF** the examples above…

Comment: So `MqBufferGetContext, MqDumpGetContext` would be two matches? I suggest you show some example input and output. "if ... is input, it will match ..., ..., and ..." And don't shout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might use a negative [lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `(?!` if it is supported to assert that `MqErrorGetContext` is not present.

You could use a word boundary `\b` for it not be part of a longer match.

[`^(?!.*\bMqErrorGetContext\b).*Mq\w+GetContext.*$`](https://regex101.com/r/WyY3S5/2)

Comment: I use TCL-regex: the after test. the regex have to be
    ^(?!.*\mMqErrorGetContext\M).*Mq\w+GetContext.*$

Answer (score 1):

Almost there, try it like this:

```
^.*Mq(?!Error)\w+GetContext.*$
```

When you use the negative lookahead, the sequence to look at must be ahead of it.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/UNMqxl/2)

Comment: @AndreasOtto Note that the `^.*Mq(?!Error)\w+GetContext.*$` [won't match `MqError________________GetContext` either](https://regex101.com/r/UNMqxl/3). Probably, you want `^.*Mq(?!ErrorGetContext)\w+GetContext.*$`